# Is it possible to create a Microsoft SMO SQL connection using server credentials in powershell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

So I have the following code which I believe creates a connection to the local SQL server on my machine using windows credentials.

```
$ServerObj = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") "(local)"
```

Is it possible to specify that I want to use server credentials to connect instead?

i.e. connect using a server username and password rather than my windows credentials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
$server = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(DATA_SOURCE)
$conContext = $server.ConnectionContext
$conContext.LoginSecure = $false
$conContext.Login = LOGIN_NAME
$conContext.Password = LOGIN_PASSWORD
$db = $server.Databases.Item(DATABASE_NAME)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked almost perfectly. I did have to set `$conContext.LoginSecure = $false` so I could set the username and password first though.

Comment: Lol. Thanks @pberry. I do have that on my original script as well but didn't copy it over. Happy it worked out for you.

Answer (score 3):

I always like this approach, so I don't have to write the password in my scripts..

```
# Get Credentials
$credential = Get-Credential -username MyAdminAccount -Message "Account credentials"
$username  = $credential.UserName
$password  = $credential.Password
$password.MakeReadOnly()
$creds = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential($username, $password)

# Create Connection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$srv; Database=master; Integrated Security=false"
$SqlConnection.Credential = $creds
$SqlConnection.Open()

# SQL Statement 
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0
$SqlCmd.CommandText = 'Select * from yourTable' 
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
```

Answer (score 1):

You can so something like this -

```
$srv = new-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(SourceServerName);  #New SMO Object
$db = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database;   #New Database Connection Object
$db = $srv.Databases.Item(SourceDatabaseName);  #Database Information stored in $db
```

If you have credentials, then you can build a connection string as follows -

```
$ConnectionString = server=*serverName*;database=*databaseName*;user id=*userName*;password=*passWord*;  #For SQL Credentials
$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection($ConnectionString)
```

**or**

```
$ConnectionString = "server=*serverName*;database=*databaseName*;user id=*domain\username*;password=*passWord*;trusted_connection=true;"   #For Domain credentials
$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection($ConnectionString)
```

But the above method is highly susceptible to SQL Injection. If you are little/not at all concerned over security then you can try something like the aforementioned.

You can also look at other solutions, specially the PowerShell module [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/) [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/connecting-powershell-to-sql-server-using-a-different-account/). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Vivek but I think I might have phrased the question wrong so I've edited it. I can connect to the database using this method if I login using administrator credentials and give the windows users sysadmin privileges. I want to know if it's possible to just use the server admin credentials from the get go.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to this. The links you gave are super useful.